# Count alphabets in C using log functions(without math.h) and arrays

Tags: c, arrays, count, character, logarithm

I'm facing a slight problem with one of my projects. I am supposed to write a c program to calculate each character present in the input/file. (It's supposed to be a basic program.) The constraints - I cannot use the math.h library to produce log functions and obtain an output in the format:

```
    1                                           
    5   1 2 0 2 2 5 8     4 3 6 6 2   5 5 7 2 1 1   2   
    7 9 8 1 7 2 4 1 0 0 4 5 0 2 2 5 2 6 3 6 6 3 7 0 2 2 
    A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

The program is supposed to count the number of occurrences of each alphabetic letter (case insensitive) in the stdin input stream and display a histogram.

As you can see, the output is formatted vertically with each line printing the base 10 number of the position of the character. 
Now, this might seem silly, but what I have so far is this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <ctype.h>

    /*
    int logBase10 (int num) {
       method to calculate the log base 10 of num
    }
    */

    int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
        char alpha;
        int count = 0;
        int ascii[128] = {0};

        while ( (alpha = getchar()) != EOF) {
            count++;
            ascii[(int)alpha]++;
            alpha = getchar();
        }

        printf("Char \t Count \n");
        printf("------------------------\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < 127; i++) {
            if(ascii[i] > 0) {
                printf("%c \t %d \n", i, ascii[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Which produces an output like this:

```
    Char     Count 
    ------------------------

         5 
         93 
    ,    6 
    -    2 
    .    3 
    ;    2 
    C    2 
    I    6 
    N    1 
    T    1 
    W    2 
    a    26 
    b    5 
    c    8 
    d    13 
    e    55 
    f    11 
    g    7 
    h    28 
    i    32 
    k    3 
    l    26 
    m    17 
    n    31 
    o    27 
    p    12 
    q    1 
    r    26 
    s    22 
    t    42 
    u    11 
    v    8 
    w    8 
    y    13 
    z    1
```

First off, my program is printing unwanted ascii characters (, ; - etc) and I am working on changing the print function to be more vertical, but I cannot figure out the log method at all. I know log(10) is 1 because 10^1 is 1, but I am having trouble figuring out how to use this to create the method itself. Also, for the extra characters, I tried using:

```
    if(ascii[i] > 65 || ascii[i] < 90 || ascii[i] >= 97 || ascii[i] <= 122 ) {
        printf("%c \t %d \n", i, ascii[i]);
    }
```

to no avail. Trying that produced more gibberish characters instead.

Any help/feedback is appreciated.

- Soul

Comment: Note: Rather than `char alpha;`, use `int alpha;` to distinguish the return values of `fgetc()`:  typical 256 `unsigned char` and `EOF`.

Comment: As for your check for a letter: `a > 65 || a < 90` will be true for any `a`. It is recommended to use character literals `'A'` instead of hard-coded ASCII values, `65`. You also might want to have a look at `isalpha` from `<ctype.h>`.

Comment: `int ascii[128]; ...  ascii[(int)alpha]` is dangerous when `alpha < 0 || alpha > 127`.  `int alpha; int ascii[UCHAR_MAX+1]; ... ascii[alpha]` is better.

Comment: I reckon you need the log function to determine the height of the display, i.e. the max. number of digits. You don't really need log for this: Divide the highest count by ten repeatedly and keep track of how often you could divide before reachng zero.

Comment: This questions is IMHO not a good one the way it's asked atm. This is too much context. Try to be more specific about what *exactly* you need and add information about what you *tried* and *why* you think it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments, although I am more confused. I tried changing alpha to char and using if( isalpha(ascii[i]) ) with my condition, but then the program is printing nothing. Sorry.

Comment: Your loop also skips every other letter, because it calls `getchar` twice, once at the end of the loop and then in the loop control. You have run reading and test for `EOF`together, so you should remove the second call to `getchar`. Alternatively, read a char into `alpha` once before the loop, then check `(alpha != EOF)` and keep the `getchar` at the end of the loop body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commenters have already pointed out issues with your code. Here's a version that counts only letters and prints vertical labels. It doesn't need `<ctype.h>` or `<math.h>`.

- Each character hets a letter index which is a number from 0 to 25 for upper and lower case letters and −1 if the character isn't a letter. That reduces the array size to 26.
- You could find out each digit with elaborate calculations, but the easiest way is to print the number to a string. `snprintf` does this for you. You can right-align the number with a field width. The maximum value for a typical `int` is about 2 billion, which has 10 digits. You should account for that, even if you had to pass in the whole Moby-Dick plus the Bible to get that many counts.
- You can test whether you should start printing by assuming a width of ten digits first and checking whether the maximum count has ten digits, that is whether it is 1,000,000,000 or higher. Then divide that limit by 10 in each iteration.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// return letter index or -1 for non-letter
int letter(int c)
{
    if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') return c - 'a';
    if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') return c - 'A';
    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int count[26] = {0};        // letter counts
    char label[26][12];         // buffer for printing numbers
    int limit = 1000000000;     // smallest 10-digit number
    int max = 0;
    int i, j;

    // read and count letters
    while (1) {
        int c = getchar();

        if (c == EOF) break;

        c = letter(c);
        if (c >= 0) count[c]++;
    }

    // write auxiliary labels
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        snprintf(label[i], sizeof(label[i]), "%10d", count[i]);
        if (count[i] > max) max = count[i];
    }

    // print vertical labels
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if (max >= limit) {        
            for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                putchar(' ');
                putchar(label[i][j]);
            }
            putchar('\n');
        }
        limit /= 10;
    }

    // print horizontal rule
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        putchar('-');
        putchar('-');
    }
    putchar('-');
    putchar('\n');

    // print letters
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        putchar(' ');
        putchar('A' + i);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

On your example, it produces:

```
         1                                          
 5   1 2 0 2 2 5 8     4 3 6 6 2   5 5 7 2 1 1   2  
 7 9 8 1 7 2 4 1 0 0 4 5 0 2 2 5 2 6 3 6 6 3 7 0 2 2
-----------------------------------------------------
 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, you have saved the day. I am trying to understand your (Auxiliary labels) code portion and will hopefully understand before copying willy nilly. (Also, loved the little (sarcasm?) for Moby Dick or Bible). Kudos.

Comment: No sarcasm involved. Your example text is the opening paragraph of Moby-Dick and both Moby-Dick and the Bilble are examples of long books. The labels are just strings to which the numbers are printed, padded with spaces to the left. They are then printed column-wise instead of the usual row-wise representation. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to figure out how many digits that you'll need is to use sprintf to convert the integer count to a string, and then use strlen to find out how many digits you have.  For example:

```
char str[20] = {0}; // 20 digits should be enough for your case

for (i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
    sprintf(str, "%d", ascii[i]);
    num_digits = strlen(str);
    printf("%d has %d digits\n", ascii[i], num_digits);
}
```

I didn't test the code, but it should be close.

Answer (score 1):

Some pseudo code

1. Find max count
2. Find width of that count when printed  `w=sprintf(buf, "%d", mxcnt)`
3. Loop `w` times (wi = 0 to w - 1)

   1. for each non-zero count

      1. form string `sprintf(buf, "%*d", w, count[i])`
      2. print `buf[wi]` character
      3. print space
   2. print \n